# Chrome Automatically Highlighting Address Bar On New Tab Open

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've created a custom new tab page for Google Chrome to use myself but whenever I open a new tab, Chrome automatically focuses the URL bar at the top of my browser. Is there a way to disable this feature?

I'm using the Custom New Tab URL extension.

[image: Highlight]

Comment: I think it's impossible because the default New tab behaves the same.

Comment: huh, darn. I thought there was some setting in Google Chrome